# How to sync role with permission using laravel sanctum with laravel spatie permission

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-sanctum

Spatie-Permission uses Guard "Sanctum" with requesting from API using Sanctum.It cause error when i tried to create and assign permissions to roles

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Permission Created Successfully",
    "user": {
        "guard_name": "sanctum",
        "name": "assign_",
        "updated_at": "2023-06-19T10:03:30.000000Z",
        "created_at": "2023-06-19T10:03:30.000000Z",
        "id": 5
    }
}
```

i am working on laravel 10.8, i have installed spatie/laravel-permission:5.10 and laravel/sanctum: 3.2. Actuall problem comes when i tried to create role or permission because it save new entries with the Guard "sanctum".I am wondering about this because Sanctum uses Web Guard but here it make a problem but it cause error.

```
 $permission = Permission::create(['name' =>  $request->input('name')]);
        $allpermission = Permission::all();
        $role_admin = Role::findById(1);
        $role_admin->givePermissionTo($permission);
        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'Permission Created Successfully',
            'permission' => $permission,
            'role_admin' => $role_admin,
        ], 200);
```

> error:

> Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\RoleDoesNotExist: There is no role with id `1`. in file D:\dm\maug\maug\vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\src\Exceptions\RoleDoesNotExist.php on line 16